# How do I get CDATA and pass it to the inner html of a Div?

Tags: javascript, cdata, sparse-data

I am trying to grab pre parsed CDATA and pass it to a div's inner html. I need this to happen from an iframe - the CDATA is in the parent. The service I'm using only allows for embedded content.
This is the data [CDATA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1G3oq.png)

The code I am using is this.

```
<body>
<div id="test">change</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var IDer = document.getElementByClassName("gon.user_id").innerHTML;
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = IDer;
</script>
</body>
```

I was expecting the gon.user_id to fill the div's inner html.

Comment: There is no getElementByClassName.. did you perhaps mean [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByClassName)?  Also a class name cannot contain a period/dot (`gon.user_id` is not a valid className)

Comment: Thanks that was actually helpful. I see now that this is a variable.